# Is there a way to rerun groovy tests which have @Ignore in the method itself

Tags: groovy, automated-tests

I have tests which have `@Ignore` in the test itself:

```
@Ignore ("fix the test")
@Test
void test_addition() {
}
```

Is there  a way to rerun the tests with `@Ignore` in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-run"?  They weren't run in the first place.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to run just tests with `@Ignore`?

Comment: Yes, Durandal,thats what I want to know. Is there a way in jenkins to run those groovy tests with @Ignore annotation in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JUnit 4+ will not run test methods annotated by @Ignore. Period. In order to run your sample test you will have to comment out (if not delete) the annotation:

```
// @Ignore ("fix the test")
@Test
void test_addition() {
}
```